# How to add a member in a group in openDJ LDAP using openDJ LDAP SDK (Java)?

Tags: java, ldap, opendj

This is my group details where I would like to add more members using openDJ LDAP SDK.

```
objectClass: groupofuniquenames (structural)
objectClass: top (abstract)
cn: Directory Administrators
ou: Groups
uniqueMember: uid=hmiller, ou=People, dc=example,dc=com
uniqueMember: uid=kvaughan, ou=People, dc=example,dc=com
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for the answer, but an example has been added to the OpenDJ SDK Samples, and has been documented in the Developers guide : http://opendj.forgerock.org/doc/dev-guide/index.html#updating-static-groups

Kind regards,

Ludovic